# How can I access and modify a global variable across multiple files?

Tags: c, linker, global-variables

Like the title says, I want to create a system where two programs can access and modify the same global variable.

I've created a directory that has the files 1.c, 2.c, foo.c, and foo.h.

1.c:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    printf("foo is %d\n", foo);
    sleep(7);
    printf("now foo is %d\n", foo);
}
```

2.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    increment();
    printf("2.c is incrementing foo. foo is now %d\n", foo);
}
```

foo.h:

```c
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern int foo;
void increment(void);

#endif
```

foo.c:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int foo = 5;

void increment(){
    ++foo;
}
```

I compile with the following compilation commands:

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc 1.c foo.o -o 1.out
gcc 2.c foo.o -o 2.out
```

And then I run it with `./1.out` `./2.out`, ensuring that 2.out runs before the sleep() finishes in 1.out. The result is the following:

```
./1.out 
foo is 5
now foo is 5
```

```
./2.out 
2.c is incrementing foo. foo is now 6
```

My theory is that when 1.c and 2.c are linked with foo.o, they both get their own local copies of foo, and thus when one program modifies foo the other program's version goes unmodified. Is it possible to create one global variable that can be shared and modified across multiple files?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Global variables are part of the process, each process has its own memory.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations, then, to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want something permanent after the program finishes, put it in a file.

Comment: If the programs are running at the same time, use shared memory or some other form of inter-process communication.

Comment: Do you have any links to APIs that can do shared memory? I'd like to avoid using pipes, if possible

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Comment: What you're trying to do is not called 'access & modify a global variable' - it's 'inter-process communication'. Global variables are contained within one process (even if that one process is a program compiled from multiple files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, global variables are global to the execution unit (process), not global to the execution environment (system).  Standard C does not provide a mechanism to share memory between processes.  However, your platform (Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc.) probably does.  Look up "shared memory".